# Speeding Up Python Convex Optimization Using Numba/Cython

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, numba, python-cffi

I'm iterating through millions of small optimization problems in CvxPy - wondering if there's a way to speed it up with Numba?

I know Numba doesn't support CvxPy or even scipy.optimize, but is there a way to directly port the C optimization libraries - maybe using Python CFFI? Wondering if anyone has any experience/ has tried this?

Comment: Maybe you should show some code to reason about warm-starting in terms of optimization (needless to say, that warm-start theory heavily depends on what *exactly* you are trying to solve) AND cvxpy's DCP-calculations. With that description, well... you could try a lot... but maybe your problem is something hidden (and dominating your bottleneck-to-optimize). And no... numba does not sound promising. Wrapping solvers might be, but don't forget, that those need some standard-form, which cvxpy is preparing.

Comment: do you think could there be a large speed improvement from mapping solvers like ECOS or SCS in numba using cffi? wondering if there is a bottleneck preparing the problem in python and sending it over to the optimization library

Comment: Imho, you are missing the important questions. And those can't be answered without details. Do you know what cvxpy is doing? Do you know what the solver will do with the prepared problem (before trying to solve it)? As solving-time is probably dominating pure python loop-iteration, there is not much to do besides making solving faster. But... hard to say what you are doing. I don't even know where your idea of using numba comes from. There is C-based code which is slower than pure looping and numba can't touch that code.

Comment: If the problems are independent you may consider solving models in parallel. CvxPy supports warm starts which may also help.